# How can i get data from a phpmyadmin table to display in the order it is entered into the database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I am creating a Fantasy Football website and I'm having problems getting the data from my database to display in the correct order.

I need the data to display in this order GK1, GK2, Def1, Def2, Def3, Def4, Def5, Mid1, Mid2, Mid3, Mid4, Mid5, For1, For2, For3.

[image: Database Table]
[image]

As you can see the first Midfielder shown should be Ozil as he is 181 and at Mid1. However Midfielder1 shows as 176 is below 181.

The table contains the IDs of the players in the PremPlayers table i then do a join to display the data

My Select statement:

```
SELECT PremPlayers.LastName , PremPlayers.Img FROM `PremPlayers`
INNER JOIN FantasyLogin
ON PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.GK1 OR PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.GK2 OR PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.Def1 OR PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.Def2 OR PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.Def3 OR PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.Def4 OR PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.Def5 OR PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.Mid1 OR PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.Mid2 OR PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.Mid3 OR PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.Mid4 OR PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.Mid5 OR PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.For1 OR PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.For2 OR PremPlayers.ID=FantasyLogin.For3
Where FantasyLogin.ID = '$UserID' 
ORDER BY PremPlayers.PositionID
```

The issue is that it is displaying the players in order of ID and there fore when a user goes to change the player it doesn't necessarily select the correct one.

php code to display players:

```
function displayData($result){ 
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $playerno = $playerno +1;
            print "<div class='col-md-2'>";
            print "    <h3>" . $row["LastName"] . "</h3>"; 
            print "    <img class='img-responsive' src='assets/img/". $row["Img"] .".jpg' alt='No Image Found'>
  <p><br><a class='btn btn-success' href='removeplayer" . $playerno . ".php' role='button'>Pick Player " . $playerno . "</a><br></p>
   </div>";
        } 
   print "</div>";

  }
```

Comment: create a column for ordering, give it proper values, and use that

Answer (score 0):

Add a column with the order.

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD `order` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Then you can select it

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `order`
```